# how to change chmod of directories in path

Tags: linux, perl

Q How to set chmod of `a/` `a/b/` `a/b/c/` & `a/b/c/d/` to `755`

Say I have a path `a/b/c/d/` to create
I can call `mkdir -p a/b/c/d/` and it will create each of the directory in path
Now I want to set chmod of `a/` `a/b/` `a/b/c/` & `a/b/c/d/` to `755`

Note `mkdir -pm 0755 a/b/c/d/` will set chmod to `755` for only the last folder

Comment: have you tried `chmod -R 755 a/`?

Comment: @SagarRakshe: that (`chmod -R 755 a/`) also changes the permissions on the files in the directories — if there are any.  If `a` was created afresh, that's a non-problem; if `a` already existed and contained other files or directories, that could be a problem.

Comment: `chmod -R go=rX a`  For group and other, the read flag is set, the write flag is cleared, and the exec flag is copied from user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
(umask 022; mkdir -p /a/b/c/d)
```

Setting the `umask` ensures that the write bits are reset for group and other on any directories the command creates (but has no effect on pre-existing directories, of course). The directories are then created with `755` permissions as desired.  The parentheses use a sub-shell so that only the `mkdir` command is affected by the `umask` setting.  (I use `umask 022` by default; I usually don't mind people reading files, but I don't like them changing them without my permission.)

Comment: didn't work as umask removes permissions from default, which in my case is 700

Comment: You have a default unmask set to 700?  Frankly, I find that hard to believe. It means you would have no access to files and directories you create, but others would have read and write access to the files and search permissions on the directory too.  Most improbable, to say the least.

Comment: no buddy, the default permissions when dir is created is 700, so I can't set it to 755 using umask as umask only subtract permissions, and not add

Comment: That's a curious system you're on.  Which one is it?  On most systems, the `mkdir` command creates directories with 0777 permission modified by `umask`.  If yours really does create them as private then you have to mechanically chase down the path as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Its Webfaction, they were fine till Friday setting 755 as permissions, but now they are setting 700, and ruined one of my presentation to client today as everything went down

Comment: I don't recognize Webfaction as a product or company, but that's just my problem.  The POSIX standard requires [`mkdir -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) to work as I indicated.  If your environment behaves differently, then it helps if you identify it.  Also, a war story like "until Friday it worked one way; now it works another" helps people understand what you're up against.

Comment: Your answer worked, earlier I was calling umask in system call, but when called in Perl it worked as required, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

In case the directories are already created, you can change the permissions with this bash snippet:

```
path=a/b/c/d
while [[ -n $path ]]; do
    chmod 755 $path
    path=${path%[^/]*}
done
```

Comment: I am using perl version `my $p='';foreach my $j (split('/',$path)){$p.="$j/";chmod 0755,"$p";}`

Answer (score 2):

### **perldoc -f chmod**

> chmod LIST
>
> Changes the permissions of a list of files. The first element of the list must be the numeric mode, which should probably be an octal number, and which definitely should not be a string of octal digits: 0644 is okay, but "0644" is not.

### Try something like this:

```
chmod 0777, "test.txt";
```

### Note

Note chmod is a **LIST** operator meaning you can pass it a list (or array) like this:

> $cnt = chmod 0755, "foo", "bar";

Answer (score 0):

If you are presently in parent directory of 'a' we could probably do this

```
chmod 755 a ; find a/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path=a/b/c/d/
while [[ -n $path ]]; do
    chmod 755 $path
    path=${path%/*}
done
```

[buff's answer](http:///a/32931333/12337365) doesn't work for me. Here's modification to his answer that does work. Substring removal fixed, and with this approach original path should end with trailing `/` .